# Was the Tzemach Tzedek related to the Metzudos Tziyon/Dovid?

Tags: history, rabbis, chabad, family-members, genealogy

The Tzemach Tzedek (of Lubavitch)'s father's name was Shalom Shachna Altshuler. Is he related to the Metzodos Tziyon?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22539/759

Answer (score 4):

Yes the Tzemech Tzedek was the Metzudos Tziyon's great-great-great-grandson.

[Source](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A8)

Comment: On second thought, one of those "great"s is a safek because it is unclear in the source. But they're definitely related.

Comment: +1, though wikipedia doesn't bring a source.

Comment: looks like not: http://www.haoros.com/Archive/?kovetz=872&Cat=11&haoro=1