# Where can I find family history of Shalom Shachna Altshuler?

Tags: rabbis, chabad, historical-figures

I'm looking for history about Shalom Shachna Altshuler, the father of the tzemach tzedek (Menachem Mendel Schneerson), and his family afterwards till now.

Your help would be greatly appreciated in directing me to Web sites or books about him.

Comment: I'm sure there are a few Chabad forums on the internet that would be able to provide you with the right information (unless of course someone will provide here.)

Comment: I think I have to close this as too broad. As [the FAQ list](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says, "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much".

Comment: am looking for links that relate to rabbi schneor zalman altshuler (my great grand father)

Comment: @msh210 obviously they were looking for a link or something to point them into the right direction. Some sort of source and not expecting an entire book as an "answer".

Comment: @Yehoshua, all, please see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7101601#7101601 et seq. and contribute to the conversation.

Comment: Closed as off topic per the chat discussion referenced in the previous comment.