# Are Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein (the Hatam Sofer Talmid) and Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein (the Krasner Rav) related?

Tags: historical-figures, ashkenazi, genealogy, chassidic-rebbe

Are Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein (the Hatam Sofer Talmid) and Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein (the Krasner Rav) related ? Is there any "ideological" link between the two ?

Comment: Is this on-topic? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/was-the-tzemach-tzedek-related-to-the-metzudos-tziyon-dovid

Comment: maaan, this question would be much stronger if you'd [edit] in information about why you want to know whether there's a relationship, either gene- or ide-alogically. In particular, if this motivation finds its origin in Judaism, then such an edit should allay @ShmuelBrin's valid concern that this question may well be off-topic, since it's about [Jews rather than Judaism](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=274832

Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein Zatzal who was the Krasner Rav, was the son of Rabbi Baruch Bendit Lichtenstein Zatzal who was the son of Rabbi Yaakov Kopil Lichtenstein Zatzal. Rabbi Yaakov Kopil's brother was Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein Zatzal who was the student of the Chasam Sofer thus that was his great Uncle.

Comment: Thanks! Were they part of the same religious group: were they both hassidim ? Also, did the last Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein had a son ? Is the lineage still live nowadays ?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein had no children but adopted his second wife's orphaned children.  His adopted daughter's husband assumed the position of the current Krasner Rabbi.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Moshe.  Can you provide sources for this information?